# Run multiple lines in CMD with Params for each from windows RUN?

Tags: cmd

I am trying to set a maximum cpu limit with powercfg through CMD using the Run option (win+R). I've tried many combinations from multiple websites and none have worked. What am I doing wrong.

One line used in CMD:

```
Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor PROCTHROTTLEMIN 50
```

Second line used in CMD

```
Powercfg -setactive scheme_current
```

Setting a powercfg adjustment through CMD requires 2 entered lines.

Failed combinations I've tried:

```
CMD /k ""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor PROCTHROTTLEMIN 50"" & ""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "Powercfg -setactive scheme_current""

CMD /k ""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor PROCTHROTTLEMIN 50"" && ""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "Powercfg -setactive scheme_current""

CMD /k "Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor PROCTHROTTLEMIN 50" & "Powercfg -setactive scheme_current"

CMD /k ""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor PROCTHROTTLEMIN 100" & "Powercfg -setactive scheme_current""

CMD /k ""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor PROCTHROTTLEMIN 100" && "Powercfg -setactive scheme_current""
```

I am using a program(phrase express) to replace text based on detection of custom keywords, so this makes the process very fast without having to manually enter all of the lines. So I could type CPUTHROTTLE > replaces with code > prompt for PROCTHROTTLEMIN varitable (which is where 50 is) > enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor PROCTHROTTLEMIN 50;Powercfg -setactive scheme_current}"
```

or this:

```
CMD /k "Powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor PROCTHROTTLEMIN 100 & Powercfg -setactive scheme_current"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting your commands in a parameterized batch script `cputhrottle.cmd` like this:

```
@echo off
powercfg -setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_processor PROCTHROTTLEMIN %~1
powercfg -setactive scheme_current
```

and save the script to a folder in your PATH. That way you could simply run `cputhrottle 50` from the Run dialog.